# Time out Error on Azure Container Instance for flask api

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-container-instances

My flask api have only one route i.e. '/predict'. It take some data as input and provide predicted data as output. It takes 6 minutes on local machine to run on complete data.
I created docker image and pushed the image on azure container registory through yaml pipeline using azure devops. Image is built on linux and python 3.9, image size is 1.4gb. I hosted this image on azure container instance.
As I hit the instance url, it goes in infinite time. And the logs of azure container shows time out error. when I test on small dataset, it works properly.  what can I do to resolve it? Can instance time out be increased? is default time is 5 mins? is there any option to increase the time out on yaml file?  Everething is set to default in my project

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it is taking 6 mins in your local machine, it may take more time in ACI if you allocate less resources. If your container takes longer time to start up, it will be terminated. You can increase the timeout value by setting the `--timeout` parameter when you create the container instance.

```
apiVersion: '2018-10-01'
location: eastus
name: <aciname>
properties:
  containers:
  - name: <containername>
    properties:
      image: <image>:<latest>
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 4
          memoryInGB: 16
      command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - sleep 600 # This will sleep for 10 minutes
      ports:
      - port: 80
  osType: Linux
  ipAddress:
    type: Public
    ports:
    - protocol: tcp
      port: '80'
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
  timeout: 600 # This will set the timeout to 10 minutes
```

Please note that increasing the timeout value may not solve the underlying issue. It is also worth considering reducing the image size by utilizing a multi-stage Dockerfile. This approach helps ensure that the final image only includes the necessary packages and dependencies. For more information on multi-stage Dockerfiles, you can refer to the following link: [Multi-stage Dockerfile | Docker](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/)
you can try increasing the CPU and memory resources allocated to the ACI instance to see if that helps